# how to change logic from inside return to outside return

Tags: reactjs

I have the Tooltip component with the prop title. I would like to change the logic from the Toolip component with title prop to outside the render so it becames more readable. 
How I can do this please?

```
<Tooltip
        title={collapsed ? formatMessage({ id: 'general.sideBar.help.expand' }) : formatMessage({ id: 'general.sideBar.help.collapse' })}
        placement="right"
        enterDelay={500}
      >
```

```
import React from 'react';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import CONSTANTS from '../../../../../constants';
import Icon from '../../../../shared/components/common/Icon';
import {
  CollapseButtonWrapperStyled,
  CollapseButtonIconWrapperStyled,
  CollapseButtonStyled
} from './styled';

const { ICONS } = CONSTANTS;

const CollapseButton = props => {
  const {
    intl: {
      formatMessage
    },
    collapsed,
    onClick
  } = props;

  return (
    <CollapseButtonWrapperStyled onClick={onClick}>
      <Tooltip
        title={collapsed ? formatMessage({ id: 'general.sideBar.help.expand' }) : formatMessage({ id: 'general.sideBar.help.collapse' })}
        placement="right"
        enterDelay={500}
      >
        <CollapseButtonStyled>
          <CollapseButtonIconWrapperStyled>
            <Icon
              path={ICONS.DOUBLE_ARROW_LEFT}
              size={16}
              viewBoxSize={24}
            />
          </CollapseButtonIconWrapperStyled>
        </CollapseButtonStyled>
      </Tooltip>
    </CollapseButtonWrapperStyled>
  );
};

CollapseButton.propTypes = propTypes;

export default CollapseButton;
```

Comment: You could use `useCallback` and define the logic function inside the component

Comment: How would it looks like? dont used this hooks before..

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Set a variable to the value that you want to pass to Tooltop and use the variable in your JSX.

```
const CollapseButton = props => {
  const {
    intl: {
      formatMessage
    },
    collapsed,
    onClick
  } = props;

  const tooltipTitle = formatMessage({ id: collapsed ? 'general.sideBar.help.expand' 'general.sideBar.help.collapse'})

  return (
    <CollapseButtonWrapperStyled onClick={onClick}>
      <Tooltip
        title={tooltipTitle}
        placement="right"
        enterDelay={500}
      >
    ...
```

You could also use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make it more compact. The above is arguably more readable though.

`` formatMessage({ id: `general.sideBar.help.${collapsed ? 'expand' : 'collapse'}` }) ``

Comment: Hi @Jake, I wrote like you say with the 
```
 const tooltipTitle = formatMessage({ id: `general.sideBar.help.${collapsed ? 'expand' : 'collapse'}` });
```
But now I get the a error in the console saying (react_devtools_backend.js:6 [React Intl] Cannot format message: "general.sideBar.help.expand", using message id as fallback.)

Comment: That sounds like an error inside your `formatMessage` function. I think you'll need to look there and see why it might not be handling `general.sideBar.help.expand` as input.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this logic as a const variable before the return and calling the name variable inside the return. Will make more easy to read

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Tooltip
} from '@material-ui/core';
import CONSTANTS from '../../../../../constants';
import {
  CollapseButtonWrapperStyled,
  CollapseButtonIconWrapperStyled,
  CollapseButtonStyled
} from './styled';

const { ICONS } = CONSTANTS;


const CollapseButton = props => {
  const {
    intl: {
      formatMessage
    },
    collapsed,
    onClick
  } = props;

  const tooltipTitle = formatMessage({ id: `general.sideBar.help.${collapsed ? 'expand' : 'collapse'}` });

  return (
    <CollapseButtonWrapperStyled onClick={onClick}>
      <Tooltip
        title={tooltipTitle}
        placement="right"
        enterDelay={500}
      >
        <CollapseButtonStyled>
          <CollapseButtonIconWrapperStyled>
            <SvgIcon
                  size={16}
            >
              <path d={ICONS.DOUBLE_ARROW_LEFT}/>
            </SvgIcon>
          </CollapseButtonIconWrapperStyled>
        </CollapseButtonStyled>
      </Tooltip>
    </CollapseButtonWrapperStyled>
  );
};

CollapseButton.propTypes = propTypes;

export default CollapseButton;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.